# Kth largest element using in-order traversal without knowing the height of the binary search tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

Can we find the **kth largest element using inorder traversal without knowing the height of the binary search tree?**
Or is there a way where we make a new pattern of **traversal like "RIGHT ROOT LEFT"**

Comment: If your question is can we run through a binary decision tree by doing right then left instead of drilling down, look for breath first search

Comment: just do an inorder traversal backwards.   Note, however, that if you're in a job interview and the interviewer asks you how to find the Kth largest element in a BST, he's gonna want to know how you can make it work in log(N) time.

Comment: Thanks for the comments i have found some way to get it done with "RIGHT ROOT LEFT" traversal pattern

Answer (score 1):

*Can we find the kth largest element using inorder traversal without knowing the height of the binary search tree?*
Yes we can.
We can do that using some extra space.
We do not necessarily need to do `RIGHT-ROOT-LEFT` to find out `kth` largest element (Although doing so would avoid usage of extra space).

There are several approaches.

The most basic one is to have a queue.

Whenever you are traversing inorder-ly, keep inserting the values in the queue.
Needless to say, as it is a binary search tree, the queue will be sorted.
Thus the `kth` largest element is at `queue.size() - 1 - k` index. (Assuming that `0th` largrst is the maximum element, `1st` largest is 2nd maximum and so on)
This approach would require `O(n)` extra space regardless of `k`

To optimize the space used, we can use the information about `k`
Note that we only need element at `(queue.size() - 1 - k)`th index. Thus
we can have a queue of size `(k+1)`. Before inserting an element, we will check if the queue has more than `k` element, if it has, we would remove one element from front as we do not require it.
After the traversal is done, the `kth` largest element would be at the front of the queue.

Here is the java implementation of both the approaches :

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Node {
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    static Queue<Integer> efficient = new LinkedList<>();
    static Queue<Integer> complete = new LinkedList<>();

    Node(int n) {
        this.data = n;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }

    public static void inorder(Node node, int k) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        inorder(node.left, k);
        if (efficient.size() > k) {
            efficient.poll();
        }
        efficient.add(node.data);
        complete.add(node.data);
        System.out.println(efficient.toString());
        inorder(node.right, k);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = new Node(7);
        root.left = new Node(4);
        root.left.left = new Node(1);
        root.left.right = new Node(5);
        root.left.right.right = new Node(6);
        root.right = new Node(9);
        int k = 2;
        inorder(root, k);
        System.out.println("Efficient queue size : " + efficient.size() + " " + efficient.peek());
        System.out.println("Full queue size : " + complete.size() + " " + complete.toArray()[complete.size() - 1 - k]);

    }

}
```

Run this and you will know how efficient queue grows.
**Please note** that here, `k` should be less than the number of nodes in the tree. If it is not, then the answer would be the smallest element.

Other approaches uses a `heap` for more general solution. In such cases the tree is not required to be a binary search tree.

Comment: Great! But this needs some extra space. can we do something else to traverse only k nodes (once k is reached we will display that value).

Comment: No, I think, for that `RIGHT-ROOT-LEFT (post order)` traversal is required.

Comment: Post order traversal is 'Left - Right - Root' (up to my knowledge). I have just mentioned 'RIGHT-ROOT-LEFT' as a separate pattern (Just for solving the problem).

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

- let x be the node corresponding to the minimum element of the tree (e.g. `x = T.root; while (x->right != NULL) { x = x->right; }`)
- Now repeat `x = x.predecessor()` k-1 times (obviously, take care of edge case)
- return `x` (you've found the `k`-th largest element in the tree)

Implementing predecessor and successor methods on a BST isn't hard, and it's easy when nodes have an additional pointer to parent node.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a simple binary tree or any tree like AVL tree?

If I understand correctly, you don't need to know the height at all...
Inorder traversal - RIGHT ROOT LEFT - is supposed to go from the highest value to the lowest.

Each time you enter the function, you may increase a static variable(or send another argument to the function) - until you get to K.

You may also maintain a degree tree, and know directly where to go through that tree.